# How and where do I create long-lasting personal notes for efficient programming

Tags: note-taking, programming

While programming I constantly look up syntax, since I switch languages a lot. To make this more efficient I started to write cheat sheets for myself and I update and improve them constantly. Since this seems a good system for me, I wanted to expand on it, by using a software instead of text files, and moving to a more long-term approach.

However, when I did research on how to put this into practice, I did find hardly anything on the topic. When I asked my co-workers the answer was mostly, that they just use google search and bookmarks.

Are there good ways to store your personal notes with a long-term perspective?

I had a look at a few non-programming focused note-taking softwares (Evernote, Confluence, OneNote, TiddlyWiki). However, I wondered if there isn't something more directed to programmers, since I assumed that most programmers face this issue.

Edit to answer comments:

- It should be possible to mark code as such. At least by font, at best with syntax highlighting.
- I prefer a cloud-based service.
- I work on windows and linux

Comment: Do you need anything programming-specific, such as syntax highlighting?

Comment: Is not a requirement, but would be a nice feature

Comment: So it should be cloud based and a web app – or rather something local for a specific OS? Or something self-hosted with web app or local program?

Comment: I updated the post. I'd like a cloud-based webapp, since I work on changing OS. I would self-host if nesserary, but prefer not to.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not exactly what you are looking for, but you could use GitHub, GitLab,  BitBucket or similar version control tools.

You could simply create files and sort them into folders. In GitHub the search isn't bad either.

Answer (score 0):

My first choice and recommendation would have fallen in your already knwo [TiddlyWiki](https://tiddlywiki.com/)

It is personal, private, offline, always available, no conectivity required. It is also conveniently stored in a single file, cross platform and easily accessible. Because of this you can easily sync it using the common file sharing tools like dropbox or similar.

It is also searchable, taggable and highly versatile and extensible through scripting and has [syntax highlihting through a plugin](https://tiddlywiki.com/plugins/tiddlywiki/highlight/).

It is browser based and can also be [hosted online](http://tiddlyspot.com/) for a close to cloud based approach, or used through a node.js server.

If that doesn't fit your needs there is [CherryTree](https://www.giuspen.com/cherrytree/#downl) note taking app with a tree like outliner structure and syntax highlighting. It runs on both Windows and Linux

[Cacher](https://www.cacher.io/) and [Snipit](https://snipit.io/) are cloud based collaborative code snippet organizers.

<sup>Disclaimer never used any of them myself except for Tiddlywki</sup>

Comment: Single file is a drawback in the long term. After a few years it becomes too big and you don't want to sync several hundreds of MB every ten seconds while you take notes.

Comment: The node.js version uses flat files, single file for each tiddler if you prefer

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these: [Laverna](https://laverna.cc) and [Boostnote](https://boostnote.io)

The first one isn't dedicated to programmers specifically, but it does support syntax highlighting. The other is targeting programmers and offers syntax highlighting for over 100 languages.

Unfortunately, they are not cloud-based as far as I looked, but they are available on most major systems (Windows and Mac OS; the latter is available on Linux as well)